# Veu is not defined

Tags: javascript

Im learning veu and I tried a basic setup but it shows {{name}} and there is `veu is not defined` in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>VueJS Tutorial</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="vue-app">
        <h1>{{ name }}</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body> 
</html>


new Veu({
el: '#vue-app',
data: {
    name: () => {
        return "Shaun";
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It's misspelled. V*u*e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its `Vue` not `Veu`.

```
new Vue({
el: '#vue-app',
data: {
    name: () => {
        return "Shaun";
    }
}
});
```